# This amount of failures ...above, below or on average?

Tags: vps

It seems like chkservd is frequently having to restart services on our server and I was curious if the frequency was common or if we should be concerned with our VPS's reliability.
I.E., on a "good" server are service restarts common every couple weeks or should they not even happen that often?

Here's a summary of the frequency of failures + restarts for the month of July:

```
July 30 named
July 20 httpd
July 19 httpd
July 16 httpd
July 10 httpd
July 8  imap, mysql, spamd
July 6  named
July 3  named
```

Server details:

```
cPanel 11.24.5-R37629 - WHM 11.24.2 - X 3.9
CENTOS 5.3 i686 virtuozzo on host
VPS Hybrid Server
```

Answer (score 1):

If your services are going down *ever*, something is wrong. Period.
Why are they failing? Is there any more detail in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard that memory is the culprit.

To confirm, check `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages`.

Look especially for [`oom-killer`](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) entries.

Answer (score 0):

Services (Daemons really) going down is a bad thing sure, but they do sometimes do that, especially for these reasons: running out of memory, failing to get locks on files (disk space or nas issues), hard locking (often cpu cooling issues or really bleeding edge release use).

I suspect the first.